# Spring controller returning multiple responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I am a beginner at Spring MVC and I have a quick question to ask. I searched all over Google for days to find the most efficient way to go about this problem:

I have a request that's coming in to Spring MVC controller. I want to send a response but wait for however many seconds and return another response to the same client. I was thinking about using ThreadExecutor or using Callable but I am not sure if that's the way to go.

Does anyone have any tutorials/examples or hints that can quickly get me started?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is what you want to do ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992153/ajax-long-polling-in-java-spring-mvc-session-scope-issue

Comment: I would I have done on it on the client side, not the server.

Comment: I can't do it on the client side because the client sends one request and the server has to send an immediate response followed by another response

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Async processing (Which is introduced in Servlet 3.0). Here is blog from Spring team on [async support and how it works](http://spring.io/blog/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support)

Comment: Thanks Nambari for the blog! I am reading the blog and from the article, "Spring MVC will then invoke the Callable in a separate thread with the help of a TaskExecutor." How do I get the Callable from the separate thread so I can put data in and return another response?.. Or am I even approaching this blog in the right direction?

Comment: @user2929965: I didn't implement this functionality in any of my applications, so I can't tell you exactly what to do, but here is one thing I have done in other programming language which is built on similar concept http://keaplogik.blogspot.com/2012/05/atmosphere-websockets-comet-with-spring.html